# Mudblazor Datagrid Pre-loaded filter

Tags: datagrid, blazor, mudblazor

I'm using the MudDataGrid component: https://dev.mudblazor.com/components/datagrid#default-data-grid

I'm trying to add a filter as soon as the page loads, but I can't find documentation to do it.

I haven't been able to find any examples of something like this using the MudDataGrid component.

Answer (score 0):

You can see ([advanced filtering](https://dev.mudblazor.com/components/datagrid#advanced-filtering)) in MudBlazor documentation

and chang the data in `OnInitializedAsync` method

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Elements = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Element>>("webapi/periodictable");
        _selectedItems = Elements.ToHashSet();
        _filterItems = Elements.ToHashSet();
        _filterDefinition = new FilterDefinition<Element>
        {
            FilterFunction = x => _filterItems.Contains(x)
        };
    }
```

The line responsible for filtering

```cs
FilterFunction = x => _filterItems.Contains(x)
```